# How to work with onRoute in Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Can any one give me a simple example on how to use [onRoute](http://marionettejs.com/docs/marionette.approuter.html#onroute) in Marionette?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the docs you yourself link to (can be hard to spot that little paragraph at the very end of the page!), `onRoute` is a method that, if you add it to any `Marionette.AppRouter`, will be called ‘whenever a user navigates within your app’.

The method’s arguments are as follows:

1. The router method attached to the route (via the `routes` hash), for instance `showArticle`
2. This one’s supposed to be the URL path, but for some reason, it’s mostly `undefined` here
3. An array of URL fragments, usually the article ID, to continue with the article example.

Whatever you use this for is entirely up to you, but I can’t come up with any useful examples right now. I’ve used `Backbone.Router`’s `execute` method a lot though, which executes *before* the route’s handler is called, making it more useful in a lot of cases. It’s available in `Marionette.AppRouter` as that just extends `Backbone.Router`.

```
var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
{
    routes: {
        'article/:id(/)': 'showArticle'
    },

    showArticle: function(id)
    {
        // ...
    },

    onRoute: function(name, path, arguments)
    {
        // What fun stuff should we put here?
        // Keep a session alive somehow?
        // Add analytics/tracking?
    }
});
```

Comment: You saved my day with this "execute" remark! For some reason I forgot that Marionette router is an extension of Backbone's one. "execute" is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!